# Javascript - display incrementing number every second

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do something where I display a different incremented number every second but I just can't get the setInterval thing right.

Here is what I have

```
function counter() {

    var i = 0;
    while ( i < 100 ) {
        // This block will be executed 100 times.
        setInterval(console.log( 'Currently at ' + i ), 1000);
        i++; // Increment i
    }

} // End
```

But what I get is the console.log firing a 100 times, then repeating.

Thanks for all the help.

Mike

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create a setInterval once, it will automatically call function (first argument) every `1000` milliseconds (second argument). So you don't need to do it inside while, just put incrementing of `i` inside the function (first argument).

```js
function counter() {
  var i = 0;
  // This block will be executed 100 times.
  setInterval(function() {
    if (i == 100) clearInterval(this);
    else console.log('Currently at ' + (i++));
  }, 1000);
} // End

counter()
```

[setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

### Update 1

```
function counter() {
    var i = 0;
    var funcNameHere = function(){
        if (i == 100) clearInterval(this);
        else console.log( 'Currently at ' + (i++) );
    };
    // This block will be executed 100 times.
    setInterval(funcNameHere, 7000);
    funcNameHere();
} // End
```

Comment: Thanks Epsilon (and everyone for that matter) for all of the help. Worked like a charm. I love stack exchange!

Comment: Ok, it seems I am back again. When using this function, it waits until the 1st interval has passed before running. So with the demo script using 1000 it waits 1 second. For what I am trying to do, I have to have the interval set at 7000, so it waits 7 seconds to run. Is there a way to run immediately then every 7 seconds after that? Thanks

Comment: @mdumka
See `Update 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
var iter = 0;
function counter() {
    console.log('show at ' + (iter++));
    setTimeout(counter, 1000);
}

counter();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var i=0;
    var timer;
    function increement() {
     if(i<100) {

      console.log( 'Currently at ' + i )
     } else {
      clearInterval(timer);
     }
    i++;
    }

   timer = setInterval(function() {increement()}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pfq7a5n3/