# Simple JavaScript counter (without using jQuery or other frameworks)

Tags: javascript

I need a simple JavaScript counter that starts counting from 0 on page load, and counts up to a number defined in HTML.

Here is the jQuery version... how can I do the same thing with plain JavaScript?

```js
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count">200</span>%
```

Comment: What have you tried? I suggest you have a look at [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ignoring the easing, you can create a simple linear counter using [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

```js
let start // set on the first step to the timestamp provided
const el = document.getElementById('count') // get the element
const final = parseInt(el.textContent, 10) // parse out the final number
const duration = 4000 // duration in ms
const step = ts => {
  if (!start) {
    start = ts
  }
  // get the time passed as a fraction of total duration
  let progress = (ts - start) / duration 

  el.textContent = Math.floor(progress * final) // set the text
  if (progress < 1) {
    // if we're not 100% complete, request another animation frame
    requestAnimationFrame(step) 
  }
}

// start the animation
requestAnimationFrame(step)
```

```html
<span id="count">200</span>%
```

Comment: I'm seeing this error: `"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null",  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",  "lineno": 73,  "colno": 27` when your code is placed inside the stackoverflow code editor. Is that a problem?

Comment: @TinyTiger my code **is** in a StackOverflow code snippet and it runs just fine (for me anyway). Did you perhaps forget to include the HTML part ~ `<span id="count">200</span>%`?

Comment: Sorry, I was using class="count" instead of id="count". Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function counter() {
  var i = 0;
  var element = document.getElementById("output");
  var funcNameHere = function() {
    element.innerHTML = `${i}%`
    if (i == 100) clearInterval(this);
    else console.log('Currently at ' + (i++));
  };
  // This block will be executed 100 times.
  setInterval(funcNameHere, 70);
  funcNameHere();
} // End
```

```html
<div id="output">0%
</div>
<button onclick="counter();">
start
</button>
```

Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26271149/1024832

Comment: Where's the _"number defined in HTML"_? Where's the 4 second duration?