# My requestAnimationFrame function problem from number 482

Tags: javascript, html, dom, counter, requestanimationframe

- I want to display a counting number from 0 to 2022.
- I looked up and adapted the code [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)
  and [from another stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245161/simple-javascript-counter-without-using-jquery-or-other-frameworks).
- My counter goes up to 2026 for an input of 2022, where 2022 is the text content of an HTML element.
- I tested other inputs and found that the issue starts from the number 482... which outputs +1. Bellow that number, the counter works fine.
- I think it might be a Math.floor problem, but cannot get it...

Thanks in advance
And happy new Year :)

```js
function countNumbers(queryID, time){
    let count = document.getElementById(queryID)
    let finalNumber = parseInt(count.textContent, 10)
    let duration = time
    let start

    const step = timeStamp => {
        if (!start) start = timeStamp

        let progress = (timeStamp - start) / duration 
        count.textContent = Math.floor(progress * finalNumber)

        if (progress < 1) requestAnimationFrame(step) 
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(step)
}
document.onload = countNumbers('count', 2000)
```

```html
<p>Happy new year <span id="count">2022</span></p>
```