# While loop with 1second breaks

Tags: javascript, while-loop, settimeout

I am running a while loop which prints the number of iterations of the loop one after another each in one console line.

```
<script>

var i = 0;

  while (i < 10) {
    console.log("The number is " + i);
    i++;
  }

</script>
```

However, I would like to introduce a pause of 1 second between each `console.log` output. I searched on the internet and stackoverflow for solutions and came across `setTimeout()`.

```
<script>

var i = 0;

  while (i < 10) {
    setTimeout(function (){console.log("The number is " + i)}, 1000);
    i++;
  }
</script>
```

But when I introduce `setTimeout()` into my code, instead of printing each number with a pause of 1 second inbetween into a seperate console line, after one second the number 10 is printed.

Comment: Can you use setInterval instead:

var i = 0, interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("This number is " + i);
    if (++i > 9) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
});

Comment: That's not how `setTimeout` works. I think you need to read up on asynchrony a bit. Here's a good place to start: https://github.com/twang281314/frontEnd/blob/master/book/You%20Don't%20Know%20JS/You%20Don't%20Know%20JS-%20Async%20%26%20Performance(O'Reilly%2C2015).pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - display incrementing number every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271084/javascript-display-incrementing-number-every-second) and [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486)

Comment: Even if you increment the delay by doing `1000*i` you will still have same number printed each time. See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> instead of printing each number with a pause of 1 second inbetween
>   into a seperate console line, after one second the number 10 is
>   printed.

That's because you are sharing `i` which does not wait for your `setTimeout`

you can use `let` to define block-level variable inside `while` block

```js
var i = 0
while(i < 10) {
  let scopeVariable = i
  setTimeout(() => console.log(scopeVariable), i * 1000)
  i++
}
```

You can achieve same thing in various way

- using `for` loop

  ```js
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), i * 1000)
  }
  ```

  - using recursive function

```js
function increaseNumber(start, end, cur = start, interval = 1000) {
  if (cur === end) return
  console.log(cur)
  setTimeout(() => increaseNumber(start, end, cur + 1, interval), 1000)
}

increaseNumber(0, 10)
```

- using `setInterval`

```js
var i = 0
var handler = setInterval(() => {
  if (i === 10) {
    clearInterval(handler)
    return
  }
  console.log(i)
  i++
}, 1000)
```